# Как избавиться от ошибки undefined method?

Tags: ruby

При таком написании кода интерпретатор выдает `<main>': undefined method calculate_elements for #<Array:0x000000000314ef30> (NoMethodError)`

Сам код

```
class NewArrayClass
  include Math

  $l0 = 1
  $b1 = 1.2*10**(-4)
  $b2 = 1.4*10**(-4)
  $alfa = 1.2*10**(-12)
  $e = -1.6*10**(-19)
  $q = 7*10**(6)
  $E0 = -100
  $Q0 = 4.8*10**6
  $h = 0.01
  $tau = 0.01
  $eps0 = 8.85*10**(-12)
  $z = 5
  $t = 300

  $number_el = 30000
  $count_in_el = 500

  $array = Array.new($number_el + 1) { Array.new($count_in_el + 1, Array.new(3)) }
  $array[0][0][0,3] = [Math.sqrt($q/$alfa), 0, $E0]

  def initialize_array
    n1 = Math.sqrt($q/$alfa)

    i = 1

    while i <= $number_el do
      $array[i][0][0,3] = [n1, 0, -100]
      i += 1
    end
    j = 1
    hz = 0.01
    while j <= $count_in_el do
      n2 = n1*(1-Math.exp(-hz/$l0))
      e1 = (2.17/$eps0)*(n1)*(1-Math.exp(-hz/$l0))+$E0

      $array[0][j][0,3] = [n1, n2, e1]

      j += 1
      hz += 0.01
    end

    $array
  end

  def calculate_elements
    i = 1
    j = 1
    h = 0.01
    while j <= $count_in_el+1
    n1 = $array[i][j-1][0]+$tau*($q-$alfa*$array[i][j-1][0]*$array[i][j-1][1]-$b1*($array[i+1][j-1][2]*$array[i+1][j-1][0]-$array[i-1][j-1][2]*$array[i-1][j-1][0])/h)
    n2 = $array[i][j-1][1]-$tau*($q-$alfa*$array[i][j-1][0]*$array[i][j-1][1]+$b2*($array[i+1][j-1][2]*$array[i+1][j-1][1]-$array[i-1][j-1][2]*$array[i-1][j-1][1])/h)
    e1 = $array[i][j-1][2]+h*2.17/$eps0*($array[i-1][j-1][1]-$array[i-1][j-1][2])
    $array[i][j][0,3] = [n1, n2, e1]
    j += 1
    h += 0.1
    if j == 501
      i +=1
      j = 1
      h = 0.1
    end
    if i == 30001
      break
    end
  end
  $array
  end





  end

$massiv = NewArrayClass.new.initialize_array
$massiv.calculate_elements
```

Что я делаю не так? Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Разберем две последние строки:

```
$massiv = NewArrayClass.new.initialize_array  
$massiv.calculate_elements
```

Первая создает новый объекта класса **NewArrayClass** (`NewArrayClass.new`), затем вызывает его метод `initialize_array` и присваивает результат выполнения этого метода глобальной переменной `$massiv`. Это результат имеет тип **Array**.
Во второй строке для содержимого переменной `$massiv` (тип **Array**!), делается попытка вызова метода `calculate_elements` которого в классе **Array** естественно нет. В результате - ошибка.

Чтобы эта ошибка не возникала, достаточно заменить последние две строки на три:

```
$massiv = NewArrayClass.new
$massiv.initialize_array  
$massiv.calculate_elements
```

Теперь оба метода `initialize_array` и `calculate_elements` вызываются для объекта класса **NewArrayClass** и ошибки не возникает.

Удачи!